# Nesting a text inside a tag in slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

How do I nest the `'Featured'` text inside the `a` tag, given the `span`, the text, and the other `span` are siblings?

```
li
  a href="#" class="selected"
    span class="icon-before"
    Featured
    span class="icon-after"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
li
  a href="#" class="selected"
    span class="icon-before"
    | Featured
    span class="icon-after"
```

Gives:

```
<li><a class="selected" href="#"><span class="icon-before"></span>Featured<span class="icon-after"></span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul
  li
    | first text
    span.color-red.bold-g
     | (text transform)
```

Give :

```
<ul><li>first text<span class="color-red bold-g">(text transform)</span></li>
```